# Facebook webapp doesn't work

Tags: unity, 12.10, chromium, webapps

All my unity-webapps work with chromium, except for Facebook. It popped up the bar to ask me to install, I did, and the unity-webapps-facebookmessenger package was installed. However, it does not appear in the dash or launcher.

I think I've traced the problem to a missing .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications, all the working ones are there but Facebook isn't. However, I don't know what the contents of the Facebook .desktop file should be so now I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

```
steven@steven-PC:~$ ls /home/steven/.local/share/applications/
GMailmailgooglecom.desktop       livecommaillivecom.desktop
GoogleCalendargooglecom.desktop  mimeapps.list
GoogleDocsdocsgooglecom.desktop  Tumblrtumblrcom.desktop
Googleplusgooglecom.desktop      Twittertwittercom.desktop
Launchpadlaunchpadnet.desktop
```

Comment: Could someone maybe post the contents of their .desktop file for Facebook?

`cat ~/.local/share/applications/Facebook<tab>`